# Office word: typing Sanskrit with English in the same document

Tags: microsoft-word, fonts

I am trying to type in Sanskrit and English on Word 2007 under Windows 10. The font I have chosen in Sanskrit 2003. I have also tried Kokila. The font size of Normal style for English and complex script (Sanskrit) is set to 10 (Body +CS). But, when I switch to Sanskrit (Alt+Shift), the font size becomes 9 (eg. संस्कृत्), instead of 10 for complex script. I have to select the portion again to resize to 10. I have attached my font settings for Normal Font, [Normal setting for complex font](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzPYI.png). Can someone help me to fix this problem?